# Groovy and grails hibernate loading child objects only once

Tags: java, json, hibernate, grails

When i try to get my class by id only first time it gives the entire detailed object including child objects and after that it gives only parent class property below is my class and code snippet i am trying so far,

> ```
> package groovyproject
>
> import groovy.transform.ToString
>
>  @ToString(includes = ['name'])   
>
> class Employee{
>
> String name
> String description
> Address address
>
>
> static constraints = {
>     name unique: true
>     description nullable: true
>     address nullable: true
> }
>
> static mapping = {
>     description type: 'text'
>     sort "name": "asc"
> }
>
> }
> ```

My code to get employee by id is

> Employee.findById(empId)

So first time i am getting below response (Which is correct)

> {   "id": 1,   "name": "User1",   "description": null,   "address": [
>       {
>         "pincode": 41102,
>         "city": "Pune",
>         "State": "MH"
>       },
>       {
>         "pincode": 23456,
>         "city": "Ahmedabad",
>         "State": "GJ"
>       }   ] }

And then always getting below response (which is incorrect)

> {   "id": 1,   "name": "User1",   "description": null    }

I am using grails version 2.5.1.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you get user via `Employee.get( empId )`?

Comment: It also works first time only!

Comment: how are you printing out the objects?

Comment: def emoloyee = Employee.findById(empId)

Comment: And returning this as return emolyoee

Comment: obviously you are printing out a JSON representation of your objects. again: how are you doing this? Also, address is defined as a single ref in your class, but the JSON shows an array of addresses.

Comment: Yes i am doing JSON.use('deep'){
        render response as JSON
    }

Comment: what is `response`? show the whole code, otherwise noone will be able to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193457/discussion-between-manoj-solanki-and-injecteer).